# React + Typescript + Styled Components pass props to keyframes & conditioning

Tags: reactjs, typescript, css-animations, styled-components, react-props

I'm trying to pass props to `keyframe` element & do some conditional animation. Here's my code:

```
import styled, { keyframes } from "styled-components";
import {
  PRIMARY,
  SECONDARY,
  DANGER,
  TEXT,
  OUTLINE,
} from "../../constans";

interface PropTypes {
  color?: string;
  variant?: string;
  size?: string;
  shadow?: boolean;
  disabled?: boolean;
  hoverAnimation?: boolean;
}

const StyledButton = styled.button<PropTypes>`
  // [... SOME CODE ...]
  animation: ${(props) => hoverAnimate(props)} 2s infinite;
`;

const hoverAnimate = (props: PropTypes) => keyframes`
        100%{
            color: ${() => {
              console.log(props);
              if (props.variant) {
                if (props.color) {
                  return `var(--color-${props.color})`;
                }
                return "#444";
              }
              return "#fff";
            }};

            background: ${() => {
              if (props.variant === TEXT || props.variant === OUTLINE)
                return "#f00";
              console.log("object");
              if (props.color === PRIMARY) return "var(--color-primary)";
              if (props.color === SECONDARY) return "var(--color-secondary)";
              if (props.color === DANGER) return "var(--color-danger)";
              return "var(--color-default)";
            }};
        }
`;
```

What am I doing wrong?

**TS complains:**

> Argument of type '() => string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SimpleInterpolation'.
> Type '() => string' is missing the following properties from type 'readonly SimpleInterpolation[]': concat, join, slice, indexOf, and 17 more.

And, `console.log(props)` prints:

```
object
```

It's like a string. I can't expand this `object` in dev tools (even if try destructure).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears like you are trying to use an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) (immediately invoked function expression) to return a "string" that would be used inside [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

But you are getting TypeScript error:

> Argument of type '() => string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SimpleInterpolation'.

because your current code:

```
const hoverAnimate = (props: PropTypes) => keyframes`
  100%{
    color: ${() => {
      if (props.variant) {
        if (props.color) {
          return `var(--color-${props.color})`;
        }
        return "#444";
      }
      return "#fff";
    }};
    ...
```

doesn't properly call the IIFE.

Here is how to fix it by calling (note the additional `()`s) the IIFE:

```
const hoverAnimate = (props: PropTypes) => keyframes`
  100%{
    color: ${(() => { // Here, at start
      if (props.variant) {
        if (props.color) {
          return `var(--color-${props.color})`;
        }
        return "#444";
      }
      return "#fff";
    })()}; // And, here
    ...
```

You need to do the same for `background` as well.

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you please tell me why I have to use IIFE in this case but not if I do similar things in styled.HTMLElement?

Comment: @Soiloui  Can you show me the code that you are talking about? As when I try, `styled.HTMLElement` doesn't exist but `styled.html` does.

Comment: I mean any HTML element like styled.button. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: [keyframe](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components/blob/main/packages/styled-components/src/constructors/keyframes.ts) functions accept strings. Whereas `ThemedStyledFunctionBase` (can be seen in TypeScript in the IDE) accepts strings as well as an `InterpolationFunction` (refer the TS definition as seen in IDE or VSCode).  It may appear complex but TS will help and guide you whenever you do anything wrong. So, in general, you should not worry much about it.